# ICloud problems

Tags: ipad, icloud, camera-roll

If I turn off my camera roll iCloud backup and it deletes all my photos from iCloud, when I turn it back on will my photos be restored to iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but if you disable, then re-enable your photos under iCloud - Storage - Manage Storage - [Your iPhone], your iPhone will re-upload the photos to iCloud.

When you disable Camera Roll, the photos are deleted from iCloud but not your iPhone.